# "Ende diesen Jahres" vs. "Ende dieses Jahres"

Tags: usage, adjective, definite-article, inflection

Ich habe beide Ausdrücke in Bezug auf etwas, das zum Jahresende eintreten soll, schon gehört.

Sind beide richtig (abhängig vom Kontext), oder ist einer davon falsch und sollte nicht benutzt werden? Gibt es eine Regel?

Comment: Nur zur Ergänzung: Das gilt nicht nur für das Ende eines Jahres, sondern auch die Mitte, Januar oder die Reisen dieses Jahres.

Comment: @OregonGhost Ich habe versucht, das in einer ausführlicheren Antwort zu illustrieren, deren Gültigkeit nicht von der Erreichbarkeit des Zwiebelfischs abhängt.

Comment: Eine wirklich wichtige Frage, weil z.B. in einer Rede die grammatikalisch korrekte Form "nicht gut" klingt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nur „dieses Jahres“ ist korrekt. Die Zwiebelfisch-Kolumne des „Spiegel“ hat dazu gleich zwei Beiträge: [*Zwiebelfisch-Abc: dieses Jahres/diesen Jahres*](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,325940,00.html) und [*Das Verflixte dieses Jahres*](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,281668,00.html). Ich habe selber zur Sicherheit erst mal recherchiert, die Version „diesen Jahres“ ist ziemlich verbreitet...

Comment: Ich möchte auch hier hinzufügen, dass die schwache Deklination tatsächlich die üblichste Wahl ist, wenn es sich um das Pronomen "all-" handelt. z.B. "allen Ernstes" und "allen Übels", obwohl "all-" in allen anderen Fällen als Artikelwort betrachtet und benutzt wird.

Comment: @Ledda: Es heißt aber "Die Quelle alles Guten" und nicht "Die Quelle allen Guten".

Answer (score 5):

Auf Grund der übereinstimmenden Position zwischen *Ende* und *Jahres* wird das Demonstrativpronomen (*diese,-r/s*) als Adjektiv (wie z.B. *letzte, -r/s*) fehlinterpretiert, die Übereinstimmung im Sprechrhythmus bestärkt die Annahme, es handle sich um dieselbe grammatikalische Konstruktion.

- Ende letzten Jahres
- Ende <s>diesen</s> dieses Jahres
- Ende nächsten Jahres

Den Unterschied erkennt man sofort, wenn man Artikel vor die Adjektive setzt:

- Ende des letzten Jahres
- Ende des nächsten Jahres

was vor Demonstrativpronomen nicht nur falsch ist, sondern auch falsch klingt:

- <s>Ende des diesen Jahres</s>

Dieses Muster ist nicht auf Konstruktionen mit *Jahr* beschränkt, auch andere Zeitbezüge werden in dieser falschen Weise genutzt.

<s>Anfang diesen Quartals</s> → **Anfang dieses Quartals**

- Anfang nächsten Quartals (Anfang des nächsten Quartals)
- Anfang letzten Quartals (Anfang des letzten Quartals)

<s>Ende diesen Monats</s> → **Ende dieses Monats**

- Ende nächsten Monats (Ende des nächsten Monats)
- Ende letzten Monats (Ende des letzten Monats)

Die falsche Form betrifft alle maskulinen und neutralen Substantive, die Zeiträume ausdrücken können (Sommer, Winter, Halbjahr), weil das Genitiv-s mit dem s in dieses zu kollidieren scheint. Das kann erklären, warum mancher Sprecher sich zu dem häufiger genutzten Klangmuster aus den Konstruktionen mit *nächster*, *kommender*, *letzter*, *voriger*, *vergangener* hingezogen fühlt.

Bei femininen Substantiven gibt es das Problem also nicht, in jedem Fall steht eine er-Endung vor dem Wort *Woche*

- Anfang letzter Woche
- Anfang dieser Woche
- Anfang nächster Woche

Der Grund dafür, warum man kaum über Formulierungen wie *Anfang diesen Tages* oder *Ende diesen Tages* stolpert, ist die Existenz des Wortes heute: *heute Morgen*, *heute Abend*. Und die für noch kleinere Zeiträume benutzten Substantive sind allesamt weiblich …

Comment: Die Beschreibung der Ursache ist korrekt und gut, aber die Bewertung als „falsch“ ist völlig daneben.

Comment: Welches *falsch* meinst du? Ich denke grammatikalisch ist es schon falsch, was nicht heißt, dass die Grammatik an sich nicht auch falsch sein könnte ;-)

Comment: Wenn ein Wort als Adjektiv verwendet wird, kann oder soll es auch so flektiert werden und genau das passiert hier. Man braucht deswegen nicht gleich ein Adjektiv _diese_ im Sinne von _aktuell_ oder _laufend_ ansetzen, aber vielleicht ist irgendwann tatsächlich auch _Ende des *diesen Jahres_ akzeptabel.

Comment: @Crissov Genau, die Sprache ist lebendig - gottseidank! Aber *`Ende des diesen Jahres`* würde ich nicht vor 2030 erwarten ;-)

Comment: Dein Argument gilt nur für das Artikelwort "dies-", andere wie "ein-" aber nicht. 

eines Jahres? Ja. Des einen oder anderen Jahres? Ja schon wieder. Es handelt sich um den Vergleich zu Adjektiveformen, das stimmt, aber im Kopf des Sprechers wird das aber auch nicht als Adjektiv betrachtet, sondern als reines Artikelwort. Ich vermute, dass man hier einfach die Beugung der Adjektiven übernimmt, da sie öfter vorkommen als Artikelwörter in diesem Fall.

Comment: @Ledda Spannend! Übrigens *ein* ist nicht nur ein unbestimmter Artikel, sondern auch ein Zahlwort. Aber was es hier wäre, tja, hmm...

Comment: @Ledda Man sollte ohnehin vermeiden, unbestimmte und bestimmte Artikel vorschnell zusammenzuwerfen, da sie sich sowohl in Flexion als auch erlaubter Wortstellung unterscheiden.

Comment: @Crissov Ja ich habe gemerkt, dass "ein" wirklich kein richtiges Artikelwort ist, aber ich finde, dass es trotzdem merkwürdig ist, weil es in dem Fall "eines Jahres" die starke Endung bekommt. Ihr habt aber rech. Wollte einfach nur ein schon existeriendes Muster darstellen, das vielleicht in den kommenden Jahren durchsetzen könnte. (Ähnlich der Vermutung von Wolf :D)

Comment: Oben habe ich auch die Redewungen mit "allen" erwähnt, was vielleicht auch dazu beitragen könnte, dass es nicht unbedingt um eine Verwechslung mit Adjektiven geht.

Comment: @Crissov: Dann sollte auch "Das erste Kapitel diesen Buches" akzeptabel sein.

Comment: @Giorgio So wird tatsächlich teilweise gesprochen, auch wenn ich es als *derzeit falsch* betrachte (ich habe den Duden hierzu nicht konsultiert). Vielleicht sollte man schauen, *wer* genau akzeptiert (bzw. akzeptieren soll).

Comment: @Wolf: Ich finde die Logik hinter diesen Formen unnötig kompliziert: wann wird "-es" und wann "-en" verwendet? Ich fände es einfacher, wenn "dieser", "all" usw immer nur eine Genitivendung hätten. Also "dieses Freundes", "dieses Buches", "dieses Jahres", "alles Guten", "alles Übels", usw. Deswegen vermeide ich die Formen mit "-en".