# Why Akkusativ in "dieses Jahr", "diesen Sommer"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, time

"Dieses Jahr", "diese Woche", "diesen Sommer" are all answers to the question "When?".

According to the rules one should use dative to answer (for example "diesER Woche"), however accusative is used. Why?

Comment: Related: [“Ende diesen Jahres” vs. “Ende dieses Jahres”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/2815/1224)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Akkusativ is used, because there is no preposition.

> Wann bist Du mit dem Buch fertig?
>   Ich schreibe es *diese* Woche fertig. (Akkusativ without preposition)
>   Ich schreibe es *in dieser* Woche fertig. (Dativ with preposition)

Using a [preposition or not](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/der-einfache-satz/angabe-eines-zeitpunkts-mit-dies-und-naechst/), defines if Akkusativ or Dativ is correct.

Be aware that also [Genitiv](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=87) can be used in some cases.

> Wann zahlst Du die Rechnung?
>   Ich zahle innerhalb dieses Monats.

Comment: @Em1, dafür warst Du schneller :)

Answer (score 9):

> Angaben eines Zeitpunkts mit dies- und nächst- ohne Präposition stehen im Akkusativ, mit Präposition im Dativ.
>
> Beispiele: Wann beginnt das Studium?
>
> ohne Präposition: diese Woche (=Akkusativ)
>
> mit Präposition: in dieser Woche (=in+Dativ)

More examples and more informations, [follow that link](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/der-einfache-satz/angabe-eines-zeitpunkts-mit-dies-und-naechst/)