# Why it is “Eines Tages” and not simply “ein Tag”?

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive, time

In a story I read recently, there was a sentence:

> Eines Tages fand Peter eine Schatzkarte!

And I wonder why it is *eines Tages* and not *ein Tag*, because *ein Tag* is what I would say normally. Is there any special reason, like a special poetic rule being used in stories or I’m wrong and the normal way is what is used there?

Comment: Ein paar kleine Korrekturen habe ich vorgenommen, aber Kommata sind nicht meine Stärke - ich vermute jedoch, dass das Komma nach "Tages" falsch ist. Der Satz ist ansonsten aber richtig, während "Ein Tag" falsch wäre, ich kann leider nicht erklären wieso. Es ist auch keine Besonderheit bei Märchen. Eines Tages wirst auch Du diese Sätze souverän meistern. ;)

Comment: And I wonder why you reverted the changes. Well, it's up to you, ...

Comment: I have read many tales (Märchen) in german for my beginning to learn this language, and that was the question that came back constantly... Cuz the first words are always those: "Eines Tages...". I finally had just accepted that like an idiom. So many Thx for asking this.

Comment: @StephaneRolland In the end it is idiomatic saying and "just accepting" is what most German people do. Being a child you often hear the words "Eines Tages" but you likely will not ask why. One day (Eines Tages) you maybe will learn the grammar in school but I guess most German natives do not remember anything of all that stuff (though they nearly perfectly speak German ;))

Comment: @StephaneRolland: Very well said, thank you for sharing.

Comment: I figure "Eines Tages" translates like "one of these days", which makes the genetive aspect more intuitive.

Comment: "Eines Tages" is the correct idiom for saying that something happened on some unspecified day. "Einer Woche" or "einer Stunde" is not correct, and "eines Jahres" is much less common. There is no particular reason why the construction works with one unit of time and not the other.

Comment: If it were not "eines Tages" I would expect it to be "einen Tag". Maybe that's because I'm accustomed to the way the accusative is used in Esperanto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eines Tages is equivalent to the English, "Once upon a time..."

It conveys generality and is non-specific. It refers to any day, not to a specific day.

It's different than ein Tag, which means one day.

Answer (score 30):

This is related to the question about "[dieses Jahr, diesen Sommer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/why-akkusativ-in-dieses-jahr-diesen-sommer)", with the difference that you are asking for an indefinite time.

As [Em1](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4942/161) already mentioned, it is an adverbial expression. You ask for such an expression using *when* (*wann*):

> Wann fand Peter die Schatzkarte?

You want to answer:

> Ein Tag.

But you answer with an *indefinite time* expression *without a preposition*. Then you have to use [genitive](http://www.vistawide.com/german/grammar/german_cases_genitive.htm) (scroll down to "4) Expressions of indefinite time"). Genitive of "ein Tag" is:

> Eines Tages.

Maybe the link in Em1 answer for the  *Adverbialgenitiv* now gets clearer.

You also can use the preposition *an* when answering the question, like [knut](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4944/161) pointed out. Then you would need dative:

> An einem Tag (fand Peter die Schatzkiste).

Comment: Schön kompakt zusammengefasst. :)

Comment: Great, I was directed here to one question I posted. According to the answer to another question I had already posted (http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/temporal-complement-and-its-correct-case), you'd need accusative to express time when no preposition is involved. So now I don't understand why sometimes you employ genitive and some other times accusative.

Comment: @martina: It's _indefinite_ time without preposition (genitive). Definite time without preposition is accusative.

Answer (score 18):

*Eines Tages* is an adverbial qualification ([Adverbiale Bestimmung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbiale_Bestimmung)). There do exist several of adverbial qualification, in that case it is a temporal adverb. Strictly speaking in that example it is an indefinite time determination and that is one of the cases where you use an [Adverbialgenitiv](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2010/09/14/der-adverbialgenitiv/), i.e. the adverbial qualification is given in [genitive](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Nomen/Kasus/Genitiv.html). That's why we typically say:

> eines [schönen] Tag[e]s

as it is also shown in the [DUDEN](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tag_Zeit_Zeiteinheit).

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Gigili Well, then what is your question?

Comment: Well, my question is what I posted above. You didn't mention anything about why it is not what I think it should be.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of the English grammar and usage, am wondering about its German equivalent. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Gigili Maybe think of "Mondays I go to the cinema" which do not refer to a specific Monday, while "On Monday (next week) I go to the cinema" is a Monday that is either specified by context or in your sentence (as I do with "next week").

Comment: Ein Tag wouldn't be correct at all. Ein Tag can be accusative or nominative, which cannot answer when-questions... you will need either a preposition or use the old fashioned genitive. That is not limited to Tag but also holds for Jahr, Monat and all the names. Most of the time it will be accompanied by a preposition but for days the genitive works. Anyway... a thing (like day) alone in accusative or nominative or dative cannot answer the question when? ever in German.

Comment: @Emanuel: I don't understand what you are trying to say. When I ask "when" I can answer the question saying "ein Tag" just like "When? One day".

Comment: @Gigili "Ein Tag" == "A day" as knut points out in his answer. You can say "Was für **ein** schöner **Tag**" == "What a beautiful day".

Comment: @ Gigili: no you can't... I mean not in German. It should be an einem Tag. No exceptions there. Saying "ein Tag" as answer to "when?" is wrong. "Ein Tag" can only answer "What?" or AT TIMES "For how long"

Answer (score 5):

If you [translate](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=eines%20tages) `eines Tages` it is *some day* or *someday*.
`Ein Tag` is *a day*.

With `ein Tag` you express one day (not two or more), or a specific day. `An einem Tag fand Peter eine Schatzkarte` would say, there is a specific day.

With `Eines Tages fand Peter eine Schatzkarte!` you express there was a day, but it does not matter, which specific day it was. It was anytime.

`Eines Tages` is more vague than `Ein Tag`.

Comment: Note, that "one day" is also a possible translation for "Eines Tages" and please remove the comma after "Eines Tages"... You should also mention that "An einem Tag" is dative.

Comment: @Em1 I removed the comma (it was a cut+paste from question). In another comment you wrote _One day you maybe will learn the grammar in school but I guess most German natives do not remember anything of all that stuff_ - Yes, you are right. Whats the `Dativ`? ;)  My answer is no answer about grammar, it's just a comment, how a native speaker understands the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

"**Eines Tages**" means the same as "**an einem Tag**" (to answer the question **When?**),

and not the same as **"ein Tag"** (which answers the question **What?**).

What the English phrase "One day" expresses is "At one day..." (something happened).

Comment: How "ein Tag" answers the "what" question? "when? Ein Tag"!

Comment: An example: Question: "Where is he?" Answer: "In his room", not just "His room" - which would be the answer to "Which room is this?". It is the same with time: You don't say "Wednesday I do (something)", but "On Wednesday I do (something)".

Comment: @The_Fritz But you can say "Wednesdays I do ..." and that's actually the genitive structure.

Comment: "Ein Tag" and no other noun neither is able of answering the question Wann? all by itself in the German language. You need either case or preposition to make it work.

Comment: @Emanuel: In German, maybe. But your example was in English where it doesn't work.