# Temporal complement and its correct case

Tags: grammatical-case, time

I'm confused about the correct case to use in a temporal complement: do you need the *accusative*?

I'm asking about the expression of a well determined time (that does not continue).
Examples may be:

> *In summer* I always go swimming
>
> *Last December*, it snowed a lot
>
> You'll have a job *in 2014*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Time indications including nouns are often introduced using a preposition (in, an). If we are talking about a fixed point in time, the preposition will need Dative.

There are many instances of time indications that don't have neither preposition nor article:

> Letzten Montag war ich schwimmen.
>
> Nächstes Jahr fahre ich in den Urlaub.
>
> Diese Woche habe ich frei.

Those are in Accusative.

Comment: Is it "fahre ich"? Or can you avoid writing the subject?

Comment: Oops... no you can't :). That is a mistake, sorry