# “einen Tag alt” – Why is it “einen” not “ein”?

Tags: grammar, article, numbers

I’m studying numbers and age expressions, and here is the sentence I don’t understand:

> Dieses Baby ist einen Tag alt.

I thought *ein Tag* is right but it wasn’t. Why?

I assumed that because I think that *ein Jahr* is in nominative here:

> Sie ist ein Jahr alt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to your confusion is that [time complements are in accusative](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/temporal-complement-and-its-correct-case). To clear why that answer is not enough to cover your question let me add the following:

You suppose that

> 'Sie ist ein Jahr alt.'

is in nominative. If that were the case you are right in writing

> 'Sie ist ein Tag alt.' (!)

since the case should be the same independent on the quantity (ein Tag or ein Jahr). However the assumption is wrong. *Ein Jahr* **is** in accusative, but it's difficult to notice it, because the accusative and nominative forms coincide.

Correctly, as you wrote, one uses accusative:

> Dieses Baby ist einen Tag alt.