# Die Bedeutung von sich voranquälen

Tags: meaning-in-context

Aus dem Vorwort zu *Der Herr der Ringe. Erster Teil: Die Gefährten* von J. R. R. Tolkien (aus dem Englischen übersetzt von Margaret Carroux, erschienen bei Klett-Cotta)

> Trotz der Dunkelheit der nächsten fünf Jahre fand ich es nun nicht mehr möglich, die Darstellung völlig aufzugeben, und so **quälte ich mich voran**, zumeist des Nachts, bis ich an Balins Grab in Moria stand.

Ich wollte wissen, was *sich voranquälen* in diesem Zusammenhang bedeutet?

Comment: Bitte stell nur eine Frage pro Frage und lege dar, wieso ein Wörterbuch nur unzufriedenstellende Antworten lieferte.

Comment: Possibly related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4941/why-it-is-eines-tages-and-not-simply-ein-tag

Comment: Im Wiktionary-Eintrag für [nachts](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/nachts) ist der in Frage gestellte Ausdruck "des Nachts" mit **(sic!)** markiert. (Welches bedeuten könnte, dass es nicht so seltsam erscheint, aber fehlerhaft ist: *Nacht* ist ja weiblich und dessen Genitiv bildet man so nicht.)

Comment: @c.p. - "des Nachts" ist nicht fehlerhaft, siehe Duden. Manche Zeitadverbien und Ortsadverbien haben ein -s am Ende, zB diesseits/jenseits, obwohl die Deklination von Seite keine Form auf -s enthält. Das sind Sonderformen.

Comment: @c.p. Community-Lexika wie Wiktionary sind zwar sehr praktisch für den schnellen Überblick und die Orientierung, wo man weitersuchen soll, aber sie ersetzen nicht den Beitrag einer wissenschaftlichen Redaktion. Zur Variante einer lexikalischen Auflistung, nur weil man sie nicht kennt, den Vermerk "sic!" zu setzen, ist schon ein starkes Stück. Dieser Vermerk wird nur in Wiedergaben von Originaltexten verwendet, wenn die Schreibung von der zur Entstehungszeit üblichen Praxis so abweicht, dass ein Fehler in der Übertragung vermutet werden könnte, sonst nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Die Bedeutung ergibt sich eigentlich von selbst, wenn man das Wort in seine Bestandteile zerlegt und deren Bedeutung untersucht:

### sich quälen

Jemand der sich quält, müht sich ab. Er tut etwas, das anstrengend, möglicherweise sogar schmerzvoll, zumindest aber unangenehm ist.

### voran

Dieses Wort bedeutet eine vorwärts gerichtete Bewegung, manchmal (aber nicht immer) ist damit zusätzlich gemeint, dass die Bewegung an der Spitze einer Gruppe stattfindet.

> Manfred kannte den Weg, also ging er **voran**. Die anderen folgten ihm.

Da der Ich-Erzähler aber offenbar allein war, scheidet diese Möglichkeit aus, und es bleibt die sonst nicht näher definierte Vorwärtsbewegung übrig.

> Der lahme Gaul trabte nur langsam **voran**.
>   Müller, wie kommen sie mit dem Projekt **voran**?

Wie das letzte Beispiel zeigt, kann die Bewegung auch im übertragenen Sinn gemeint sein.

### sich voranquälen

Das ist nun beides gemeinsam: Eine Vorwärtsbewegung, die dem, der sich bewegt, Qualen bereitet. Es bleibt offen, ob die Bewegung zu Fuß, auf dem Rücken eines Reittieres oder in einem Raumschiff stattfindet.

Der Ich-Erzähler befand sich also offenbar auf einer qualvollen Reise.

Comment: In diesem Falle nicht der Ich-Erzähler, sondern der Autor (was allerdings aus dem Zitat nicht ersichtlich ist).

Answer (score 2):

Das Verb *[quälen](http://www.duden.de/node/660188/revisions/1359075/view)* (das im vorliegenden Fall noch um das Präfix *[voran…](http://www.duden.de/node/818976/revisions/1323753/view)* ergänzt wurde) kann grundsätzlich verschiedenen Bedeutungen haben.

In dem zitierten Vorwort beschreibt der Autor, unter welchen Umständen er an seinem Buch gearbeitet hatte (der Hinweis „trotz der Dunkelheit der nächsten fünf Jahre“ bezieht sich auf den Zweiten Weltkrieg). In diesem Zusammenhang findet man für *sich quälen* in Duden – *Deutsches Universalwörterbuch* die folgende Bedeutung.

> **3.** <quälen + sich>
>   (…)
>   **b)** *sich (mit etwas, jemandem) sehr abmühen:* sich mit der Hausarbeit quälen; (…)

Der Autor erklärt also mit „und so quälte ich mich voran, zumeist des Nachts“, wie sehr er sich mit dem Schreiben des Buchs abmühte.

Der Inhalt des Buchs ist eine Erzählung über eine mühsame Reise. In diesem Zusammenhang kann *sich quälen* auch eingesetzt werden:

> **4.** <quälen + sich> *sich unter Mühen, mit großer Anstrengung irgendwohin bewegen:* mühsam quälten wir uns durch den hohen Schnee.

Diese zweite Bedeutung ist hier offensichtlich gewollt. Der Autor beschreibt seine Arbeit an dem Buch so, als hätte er die Reise, von der er in dem Buch erzählt, selbst unternommen („bis ich an Balins Grab in Moria stand“). Tatsächlich hat er jedoch nicht an dieser Reise teilgenommen und stand auch nie an Balins Grab in Moria.