# Welchen Fall benutzt man mit Phrasen wie "last year"?

Tags: grammatical-case, time

Zum Beispiel im englischen Satz "Last year I visited Germany.", welchen Fall benutzt man?

> Letztes Jahr habe ich Deutschland besucht.
>
> Letztem Jahr habe ich Deutschland besucht.

Ich glaube Nominativ und Genetiv sind ganz falsch, aber ich kann mich nicht zwischen Akkusativ oder Dativ entscheiden.

Welcher ist korrekt und warum?

Comment: [“Ende diesen Jahres” vs. “Ende dieses Jahres”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/2815/1224) - [Why Akkusativ in “dieses Jahr”, “diesen Sommer”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/4891/1224)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In German, definite time expressions that do not include prepositions use the *accusative case.*

> Nächste Woche mache ich das.
>   I'll do that next week.
>
> Ich hätte die ganze Nacht tanzen können.
>   I could have danced all night.
>
> Wir haben ihn letzten Dienstag gesehen.
>   We saw him last Tuesday.

Indefinite expressions use the genitive (*eines Tages* = "one day...").

See this Dartmouth webpage for more information about German time expressions, including the above use of the accusative case for definite time expressions: http://www.dartmouth.edu/~german/Grammatik/Zeit/Time.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason is "letzte" is not a preposition, but rather an adjective.  If no preposition exists in the sentence, then the accusative case, but also sometimes the genitive case, is used.