# Warum sagt man "letzte Woche" aber "in der letzten Woche"?

Tags: expression, grammatical-case

Warum gibt es einen Unterschied im Wort "letzte"?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/welchen-fall-benutzt-man-mit-phrasen-wie-last-year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Die Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/welchen-fall-benutzt-man-mit-phrasen-wie-last-year), die Takkat verlinkt hat, erklärt, dass man ohne Präposition Akkusativ benutzt.

"In" ist eine Präposition, die entweder Akkusativ oder Dativ nimmt. In diesem Fall gibt es keine Bewegung, deshalb benutzt man den Dativ.