# Questions on "da Alles zu einem Zweck geschaffen worden"

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I am trying to understand the highlighted phrase from this 1844 translation of Candide by Voltaire.

> »Es ist erwiesen,« sagte er, »dass die Dinge nicht anders sein können: denn **da Alles zu einem Zweck geschaffen worden**, ist Alles notwendigerweise zum denkbar besten Zweck in der Welt. Bemerken Sie wohl, dass die Nasen geschaffen wurden, um den Brillen als Unterlage zu dienen, und so tragen wir denn auch Brillen. . . .

**Questions**

1. Is *Alles zu einem Zweck geschaffen worden* an [absolute construction](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26053/traditional-grammar-on-noun-centered-phrases)?
2. Would *Alles zu einem Zweck geschaffen* (i.e. without *worden*) be grammatical or ungrammatical? (In English one would say, "The work done, he took the rest of the afternoon off," not "The work been done, . . .")
3. If both expressions, i.e. with and without *worden*, are grammatical when would one prefer to use the one to the other?
4. Is *da* an adverb?  (Had an *ist* followed *worden* giving us *da Alles zu einem Zweck geschaffen worden ist, ist . . .* I would have thought *da* was a conjunction and not had questions 5 and 6.)
5. What is the semantic contribution of *da* to the *denn*-clause?
6. Would the *denn*-clause be grammatical if *da* were not there?

**Background**

The original text does not appear to have anything corresponding to *da*.

> « Il est démontré, disait-il, que les choses ne peuvent être autrement ; car tout étant fait pour une fin, tout est nécessairement pour la meilleure fin. Remarquez bien que les nez ont été faits pour porter des lunettes ; aussi avons-nous des lunettes. . . .

Comment: A repeated _ist_ has been combined into one; the full form would be *… geschaffen worden ist, ist …*. Does that help?

Comment: @chirlu Oh yes, very much. That actually takes care of all questions, 1 through 6. Thank you.

Comment: I still finished the more elaborate answer I was writing. :-) I now think it is less about combining the two _ist_ as I thought at first, but rather that it was generally possible to drop a clause-final auxiliary. I’m not completely sure about the historical rules, though.

Comment: "Dropping a clause-final auxiliary" is indeed very concrete, and now I know what to look out for. Thanks again!

Comment: Zu viele Fragen, und letztlich geht es um Französisch, oder?

Comment: @userunknown Nein, es geht um Deutsch. Catomic versucht, den Satz der deutschen Übersetzung in seine Einzelteile zu zerlegen und den Sinn eines jeden Einzelteils zu erfassen. Dass er sich dabei am Anfang getäuscht hat, ändert nichts an der Tatsache. Und seine Fragengeschichte hier besteht fast ausschließlich aus dieser Sorte Fragen, ist also nichts ungewöhnliches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no absolute construction here. Instead, the bolded part is a subordinate clause in which the finite verb, the auxiliary *ist*, has been omitted. I don’t think any modern writer would do this (except when deliberately trying to sound old-fashioned), but it was very common in the old days. It is not inconceivable that *worden* could be dropped, too, but that would be far more unusual.

Consequently, *da* is indeed the conjunction that introduces the subordinate clause. The *da* clause justifies the statement in the main clause (the *denn* clause), which in turn justifies the statement of the preceding sentence. Or at least that is the intention of the person speaking. :-)

The part corresponding to the *da* clause in the French original is the participle construction *tout étant fait pour une fin*.

Comment: From your comment: "generally possible to drop a clause-final auxiliary." - Does this "general possibility" also explain the missing finite auxiliaries in these lines from Schiller:  "Deine Zauber binden wieder, was der Mode Schwerd getheilt.... Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu seyn; wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein!"

Comment: @Catomic: Yes, I think so.