# Akkusativ anstatt Genitiv benutzen

Tags: genitive, accusative

Der folgende Satz gehört zur Goethe-Zertifikat B1 Wortliste:

> Im Vergleich zum Wetter letzte Woche ist es heute warm

Ist grammatisch richtig? Ich glaube, es muss "zum Wetter letzter Woche" sein, weil der Satz Genitiv ist

Comment: Die Frage des Akkusativs bei Zeitangaben wird hier behandelt: [Welchen Fall benutzt man mit Phrasen wie "last year"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/welchen-fall-benutzt-man-mit-phrasen-wie-last-year)

Comment: Ohne Bezug zur eigentlichen Frage: “… ist *es* heute warm” und “weil der Satz Genitiv ist”.

Comment: Der Satz als ganzer ist niemals Genitiv.

Comment: In einem bestimmten Fall (egal ob Genitiv, Akkusativ usw.) stehen immer nur kleine Wortgruppen oder einzelne Wörter. Niemals kann ein ganzer Satz in einem bestimmten Fall stehen. Beispielsweise stehen die Verben stehen niemals in irgend einem Fall, und das Subjekt, das (bis auf sehr seltene Ausnahmen) in jedem Satz vorkommt, steht immer in Nominativ.